# Numerical integration of binomial pdf with respect to a conditional probability

Tags: statistics, integration, probability-distributions, numerical-methods

How do you numerically integrate the following loss function with respect to $\Phi(f_t)$, given $N_t=50$, $d_t=0$, $\rho=0.2$ and $\pi=0.01$?

$P(D_t=d_t)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 N_T \\
 d_t
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\int\limits_{-10}^{10} \lambda(f_t)^{d_t} \cdot (1-\lambda(f_t))^{N_t-d_t} \text{             }d\Phi(f_t)$
,with
$\lambda(f_t)=P(D_{i,t}=1|F_t=f_t)=\Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(\pi)-\sqrt{\rho}f_t}{\sqrt{1-\rho}}\right)$.

Using the following R code, I obtain 4.803584 which is not a valid solution because $P(D_t=0)\in[0,1]$. How can I solve this numerically to get a valid solution?

> d<-0;
>   N<-50;
>   rho<-0.2;
>   pd<-0.01;
>   integrand <- function(x) {pnorm(qnorm(pd),mean=sqrt(rho)*x,sd=sqrt(1-rho))};
>   integrate(integrand, lower = -10, upper = 10)